# Copying project to Eclipse?

Tags: android

There is a folder project that is done in Eclipse on another computer,  now I copy it to workspace folder on my computer, and when I open the Eclipse I found the project folder after I add it to Eclipse and there is an error that I do not know how it is solved.
When I saw the error it is in `AndroidManifest.xml` file and when I open it is empty, and the error is:

> Parser exception for
>   C:\Users\MAX\workspace\Your_Guide\AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end
>   of file.

Really need help.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can willy-nilly move a folder into the workspace. Try importing the project using File > Import > General > Existing projects into workspace, and finding your directory where the .project exists.

Comment: this problem is shown:
Project 'Your_Guide' is missing required library: '\android-support-v7-appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'

Answer (score 0):

Use the option "`Existing Android Code Into Workspace`".

`File` -> `Import` -> `Android` -> `Existing Android Code Into Workspace`.

[image]